# PHP Mapping values from DB

Tags: php, laravel, mapping

I'm trying to create a mapping between two tables which then should provide an array(expected results can be seen below).

If the user clicks a button (action_type=label) in user interface then a request is made to DB table Parameter with the action_type. With the request is always sent the shipment id and user id and action_type.

From there a mapping should be created.

I have three tables.

In table Parameter I have the needed parameters for action_type label. 
For example if I need the parameter "parcels" value then the code should be able to find the value from table shipments and take the shipment_identification value.

Table: Parameter

```
╔════╦═════════════╦════════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ id ║ action_type ║ parameter_name ║ parameter_value         ║
╠════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 1  ║ Label       ║ parcels        ║ shipment_identification ║
╠════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 2  ║ Label       ║ printType      ║ printType               ║
╠════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 3  ║ Label       ║ printFormat    ║ printFormat             ║
╠════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 4  ║ Label       ║ user           ║ username                ║
╠════╬═════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 5  ║ Label       ║ pass           ║ password                ║
╚════╩═════════════╩════════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

Table: User_configurations

```
╔════╦═════════╦═══════════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ id ║ user_id ║ user_config_parameter ║ user_config_value ║
╠════╬═════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 1  ║ 1       ║ username              ║ ABC               ║
╠════╬═════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 2  ║ 1       ║ password              ║ DEF               ║
╠════╬═════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 3  ║ 1       ║ printType             ║ A4                ║
╠════╬═════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ 4  ║ 1       ║ printFormat           ║ ZPL               ║
╚════╩═════════╩═══════════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Table: Shipments

```
╔════╦═════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ id ║ user_id ║ shipment_identification ║
╠════╬═════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 1  ║ 1       ║ 0123456789              ║
╚════╩═════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

From Database I query the current Users configuration and shipements.

The expected result would be this array. For all parameters where action_type equals label I need a value from the second and third table.

```
$request_params = [
            'form_params' => [
                'parcels' => '0123456789',
                'printType' => 'A4',
                'printFormat' => 'ZPL',
                'user' => 'ABC',
                'pass' => 'DEF'
            ]
        ];
```

I've tried solving this issue with multiple foreach loops but I'm unable to and I end up with the following:

```
foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
    $request_params['form_params'][$parameter->parameter_name] = $userConf->user_config_value;
}


Array ( [form_params] => Array ( [printFormat] => A4 [parcels] => A4 [printType] => A4 ) )
```

I understand that, currently my code is using the last value from DB for each single parameter value but how would I be able to assign the correct value from table User_configurations and table Shipments by using table Parameter for the mapping.

Kind regards,

Comment: _“How would it be possible”_ is rather too broad for a question here. Please go read [ask], and describe what you have already tried.

Comment: What are params you were send!!? `Table: Parameter id` is `User_configurations and Shipments  user_id` Right!!?

Comment: Rasa, The value which I'm trying to receive is in the parameter table. 
I want parameter printType and in `User_configurations` the is a value. I need the possibility to link them together like that.